# How to specify @XmlValue correctly in json object with loopback library?

Tags: web-services, soap, loopbackjs

I want to send the following soap xml fragment to IBM MDM Soap service using IBM loopback library version 3.22.

```
<ns2:InquiryParam xmlns:ns2="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
        <ns2:tcrmParam name="PartyId">12345</ns2:tcrmParam>
        <ns2:tcrmParam name="PartyType">P</ns2:tcrmParam>
        <ns2:tcrmParam name="InquiryLevel">0</ns2:tcrmParam>
</ns2:InquiryParam>
```

I am trying to use IBM loopback javascript library v 3.22, to send SOAP request to IBM MDM web service. I have an example soap request that I can test successfully using Soap UI. I can see the exact soap request that loopback library is sending to the IBM MDM web server and the response from the server.

javascript model object in loopback v3.22 has the following javascript fragment.

```
let tmpVar = {"tcrmParam":[{"value":"12345","name":"PartyId"},{"value":"P","name":"PartyType"},{"value":"0","name":"InquiryLevel"}]};

let partyParam={RequestControl: RequestControl, InquiryParam: tmpVar};

    Getparty.getParty(partyParam, function (err, response) {
```

...

The above javascript code fragment when used with loopback library sends the following xml fragment to IBM MDM Soap web service.

```
 <soap:Body>
    <ns1:getParty xmlns:ns1="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/port/Party">
      <ns2:RequestControl xmlns:ns2="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
        <ns2:requestID>1</ns2:requestID>
        <ns2:DWLControl>
          <ns2:requesterName>mdmadmin</ns2:requesterName>
          <ns2:requesterLocale>en</ns2:requesterLocale>
        </ns2:DWLControl>
      </ns2:RequestControl>
      <ns2:InquiryParam xmlns:ns2="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
        <ns2:tcrmParam name="PartyId">
          <value>12345</value>
        </ns2:tcrmParam>
        <ns2:tcrmParam name="PartyType">
          <value>P</value>
        </ns2:tcrmParam>
        <ns2:tcrmParam name="InquiryLevel">
          <value>0</value>
        </ns2:tcrmParam>
      </ns2:InquiryParam>
    </ns1:getParty>
  </soap:Body>
```

The error from IBM MDM Soap service is:

"ErrorMessage": "The required field is missing.",

The generated soap request must NOT have `<value>` in  tcrmParam.

What changes are need in the loopback nodejs javascript project, so that soap connector will send xml fragment

```
<ns2:tcrmParam name="PartyId">12345</ns2:tcrmParam>
```

instead of

```
    <ns2:tcrmParam name="PartyId">
      <value>12345</value>
    </ns2:tcrmParam>
```

?

Thx,

Answer (score 0):

After reading strong soap docs, I noticed I can make use of **$attributes** and **$value**, as shown below:

```
let partyParam={RequestControl: RequestControl, InquiryParam: {tcrmParam: [{'$attributes': {name: 'PartyId'}, '$value': '12345'},
{'$attributes': {name: 'PartyType'}, '$value': 'P'},
{'$attributes': {name: 'InquiryLevel'}, '$value': '0'}]}};
```

With the above code change, I was able to verify the following soap request was getting generated and the soap request completed successfully.

```
  <ns2:InquiryParam xmlns:ns2="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
    <ns2:tcrmParam name="PartyId">12345</ns2:tcrmParam>
    <ns2:tcrmParam name="PartyType">P</ns2:tcrmParam>
    <ns2:tcrmParam name="InquiryLevel">0</ns2:tcrmParam>
  </ns2:InquiryParam>
```

Thx,